# Tool for finding maximum value of a function within a given range

Tags: calculus, optimization

I have some equations of degree three and four which I actually obtained from the trendline in excel.

Now I'm interested in finding the x value at which these polynomials will give me a maximum value in a given range.

Say Y=-0.036x^3+.16x^2-.11x+2.28 and 340<=x<=370

Most of the online maxima finders give me a max value of the function which is a far cry from this range of x.

Now is there any online website or tool that can give me the maximum value of this function of x within the given range? If no, then what should be my possible course of action for achieving the desired goal?

Comment: If it's degree 3, then everything can be done with a routine application of calculus and the quadratic formula.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, but what if I have a large number of equations of variable degrees and I dont want to go through the hassle of actually solving these equations by hand? Any online tool for finding maxima within the given range?

Answer (score 2):

You can [use Wolfram|Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=maximize%20-0.036x%5E3%2B.16x%5E2-.11x%2B2.28%20on%20340%3C%3Dx%3C%3D370) by entering a query like:

> `maximize -0.036x^3+.16x^2-.11x+2.28 on 340<=x<=370`.

[image]